# npm install error on jenkins because of node-gyp

Tags: node.js, jenkins, node-gyp

i am trying tsc build and deploy on genkins. but when add dependency by npm install, it is fail because of node-gyp in bcrypt.

maybe, it is not problem about permission,

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error

is it mean that need xcode in jenkins insatance?

```
[Deploy filetalk api] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/y1/w43krbdx3f5ftk12phngh2hr0000gn/T/jenkins13670715368010697711.sh
+ npm install
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@3.0.8: versions < v5.0.0 do not handle NUL in passwords properly
> bcrypt@3.0.8 install /Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.8/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.8-node-v83-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.8 and node@14.2.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin/node" "/Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v14.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin/node /Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin/node" "/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin/node /Users/dany/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN apollo-cache-control@0.1.1 requires a peer of graphql@0.10.x - 0.13.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN apollo-server-core@1.4.0 requires a peer of graphql@^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN apollo-tracing@0.1.4 requires a peer of graphql@0.10.x - 0.13.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN graphql-extensions@0.0.10 requires a peer of graphql@0.10.x - 0.13.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN graphql-playground-middleware-lambda@1.7.12 requires a peer of aws-lambda@^0.1.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN graphql-subscriptions@0.5.8 requires a peer of graphql@^0.10.5 || ^0.11.3 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN strum-back@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dany/.jenkins/workspace/Deploy filetalk api/.npm/_logs/2020-07-30T04_43_42_201Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

is it right solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-macos-catalina-anansewaa-38b536389e8d.

it is issue about catalina